# Bind Different dataset datatables to different gridviews dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net so I dont know what I am asking is possible or not.

I have a dataset with many datatables and I need to bind each data table to a different gridview.The no. of datatables will be decided dynamically.
And the data for the data tables will be copied from a 2d array of object(array of arrays of object.
Logic is that each element of the 2d array is a row of a table and each row of the 2d array is a table and 2d array is a dataset with many tables(rows).

or any suggestions with a different approach.

Thank you.

Comment: So how many girdviews you will have will they also be dynamic accroding to tables ?

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Comment: What is it you want to archive?

Comment: @MairajAhmad The no. of gridviews will be the no. of datatables in the dataset.So that will also be defined dynamically.

Comment: @MairajAhmad The code is 500 lines long, so can you tell me which part of it  help you? Thank you.

Comment: @SollyM The details of a product will be stored like productID, VendorId,  mrp, sellingPrice.  Thank you.

Comment: If you are looking at developing a management system for your tables, then I suggest you plan it correctly so that you can use the GridViews to their full potential. But that also means being about to perhaps create a user control and pass some kind of ID that will identify the table you want to load, then do your necessary editing.

Comment: @SollyM I'll think about it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @SollyM Can I take an array of list view control and add them to the webpage dynamically? Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can create/add controls dynamically from any list you have, `DB/XML/List<>/Enumerable<>/etc.`. You just need to know if you have a List<string> which holds the names, how then do you get the list of sub-controls - e.g. Columns, Textboxes, Buttons, etc. - inside your dynamic GridView control. Alternatively you can have List<GridView> but you will need the GridViews generated prior to be added to the list. Send me an email and we can look at this in depth.

Comment: @SollyM I have altered the code to avoid using an array of list views but I would like to know more about it. For now **can you tell me how to add column names to a list view programmatically?** I have asked a question on    [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051095/add-columns-column-headers-to-a-list-view-programatically). Just hoping for a quick reply. Thank you.